# Parsing special character using Java Regex

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, ascii

I have a requirement where i need to remove those special characters from a string which are not in the array list. The current code removes all special character when found ,

```
String Modified_remark = final_remark.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
```

This code removes all special character from the string , But i want to retain certain items like Angstrom Symbol (Å) & Micron Symbol (μ)

For example if i place the allowed special character in Array , i want the code to skip the replacement and if not matching then replace with "" (Empty quotes).

```
String[] allowedChar = {Å, μ};
```

To be added more when requested by User's. Can anyone help with this logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add all the `allowedChar`s to the exception list in your regex:

```
final_remark.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F" + String.join("", allowedChar) + "]", "");
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/iQWvHI

**Update**

As Wiktor Stribiżew rightly pointed out, the this simple code breaks if `allowedChar` contains some regex special characters. Since the requirements imply `allowedChar` to contain only non-ACSII characters, we may add a condition on `allowedChar` as follows:

```
String[] allowedChar = {"Å", "μ", "]"};
String allowedChars = "";
for (String ch : allowedChar)
    if (ch.matches("^[^\\x00-\\x7F]$"))
        allowedChars += ch;
String Modified_remark = final_remark.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F" + allowedChars + "]", "");
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/94513e

Comment: What is the character is `]` or `[`? Or `-`?

Comment: Well, yes, that would break the code. But the requirement implicitly assume that the `allowedChar` would only contain characters outside the `\x00-\x7F` range, so as a reasonable trade-off we may force this condition on the `allowedChar` items.